# Creating a Matrix with ArrayLists

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

I want to create an ArrayList-matrix with n-rows and m-columns, for example

```
   1 2 3 4 5

   1 2 3 4 5 

   1 2 3 4 5

   1 2 3 4 5

   1 2 3 4 5
```

I've already written a code for creating such a matrix but my code doesn't display the values when I clear the list containing the column-data. Here is my

```
package testproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                intList.add(k);
            }
            mainList.add(intList);
            intList.clear(); //this line is probably the problem
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < mainList.size(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < mainList.get(0).size(); col++) {
                System.out.print(mainList.get(row).get(col) + ",");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to clear the contents of *intList* without clearing the
contents of mainList??

Comment: Couldn't you just declare a new ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(intList); Then add that to the mainList instead of intList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `mainList.add(intList);` you are adding a reference pointing to the intList object into your mainList rather than copying the values. You will have to create one instance of "intList" per row, and not clear anything.

Comment: sandBo00 I see... creating one instance for each row would probably kill the performance at higher amounts of rows (>=100000).

Comment: @Ramses I just tested with 120000 rows and 10 columns each, every position filled with a random integer, and that took next to no time on my machine ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just need to move the creation of intList inside for loop and now should work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
        public class TestProject {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                    ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int k=0;k<5;k++) {
                        intList.add(k);
                    }
                    mainList.add(intList);
                }
                for(int row=0;row<mainList.size();row++) {
                    for(int col=0;col<mainList.get(0).size();col++) {
                        System.out.print(mainList.get(row).get(col)+",");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have to remove the `intList.clear();` line, or else the lists will still be empty.

Comment: @Maxqueue your solution only works when you delete the row intList.clear() :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your hunch is correct. the line `intList.clear();` is the problem.
Because the `intList` is stored in `mainList` and if you clear `intList` the information in `mainList` also gets lost.
one Solution: create a `new intList` in every loop
But because matrizes are usually not variable in their dimensions - which `Arraylists` are - you should consider using `int[][] intList` for your matrizes.

Answer (score 1):

Java works with references. So in your program, `mainList` will contain 5 references to the same unique `intList`. Anything you do to `intList` will reflect in all the "rows" in `mainList`, clearing, changing a value, etc.

If you want to create a matrix you most likely want to have each "row" be a reference to a different list. This can be done by instantiating a new list in the loop:

```
package testproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>(); // This creates a new list for each row.
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                intList.add(k);
            }
            mainList.add(intList);
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < mainList.size(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < mainList.get(0).size(); col++) {
                System.out.print(mainList.get(row).get(col) + ",");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

In your program, clearing the intermediate list isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would create n- or m- ArrayLists it depends how You want to use it.

Or You create one hashmap > for each row one ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

This is my purpose to show 4*4 Matrix on arrayList

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 *
 * @author David Clavijo
 */
public class PuzzleShuffle {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> blockNums = new ArrayList<>();
        
        
                blockNums.add(1);
                blockNums.add(2);
                blockNums.add(3);
                blockNums.add(4);
                blockNums.add(5);
                blockNums.add(6);
                blockNums.add(7);
                blockNums.add(8);
                blockNums.add(9);
                blockNums.add(10);
                blockNums.add(11);
                blockNums.add(12);
                blockNums.add(13);
                blockNums.add(14);
                blockNums.add(15);
                blockNums.add(0);
                
                Collections.shuffle(blockNums);
                for(Integer i: blockNums){
                if (blockNums.indexOf(i)%4 == 0 && blockNums.indexOf(i)!=0){  
                        System.out.println("\n");}
                System.out.printf("%4d", i);
                
                }
                System.out.println("\n"+"\n"+"Matriz Random");
                
    }
    
}
```