# How to Create a Matrix from 2 existing ArrayLists (Java)?

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

I am reading contents from a text file and parsing them into separate ArrayLists.

For example, the text file reads:

```
Fruit1
Fruit2
Fruit3
Vegetable1
Vegetable2
Vegetable3
Vegetable4
```

Currently, I have a code that separates each group into its own array

```
fruits = [Fruit1, Fruit2, Fruit3]
vegetables = [Vegetable1, Vegetable2, Vegetable3, Vegetable4]
```

How do I make a matrix with *n* rows and *m* columns from these two existing ArrayLists?

My goal output is to generate a 3x4 matrix like so

```
          | Fruit1, Fruit2, Fruit3 
Vegetable1|
Vegetable2|
Vegetable3|
Vegetable4| 
          |
```

I have seen examples demonstrating initializing a matrix, however, if I update my text file to lets say a 3x20 matrix, or a 5x20 matrix, I want the code to run the same, which is where I am struggling.

Here is the code I've written for the matrix:

```
List<List<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
matrix.add(fruits);
matrix.add(vegetables);
System.out.println(matrix);
```

However, this is the output, which just combines them

```
[Fruit1, Fruit2, Fruit3, Vegetable1, Vegetable2, Vegetable3, Vegetable4]
```

How do I create a matrix, making one ArrayList the rows, and the other ArrayList, the columns?

Comment: Please follow below link you will get an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078635/creating-a-matrix-with-arraylists

Comment: I have seen this, but this did not really help

Comment: So far you have only the row and column "headers" (at leasts that's what it looks like in your demonstration). What should be the contents?

Comment: In the end, I want to compare Fruit1 to Vegetable1, Fruit1 to Vegetable2 and so on... I should have 12 comparisons

Comment: I just don't know how to put this into matrix format to later write code that compares each variable in one arraylist to the other equaling 12 comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the following matrix:

```
Vegetable1 | Fruit1, Fruit2, Fruit3
Vegetable2 | Fruit1, Fruit2, Fruit3
Vegetable3 | Fruit1, Fruit2, Fruit3
Vegetable4 | Fruit1, Fruit2, Fruit3
```

You can use the following code to use `ArrayList`s to do all the comparisons:

```
List<String> vegetables = new ArrayList<>(); // Fill the lists somehow
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

for(String vegetable : vegetables) {
    for(String fruit : fruits) {
        System.out.printf("Compare %s to %s%n", vegetable, fruit);
    }
}
```

If that's all you want, you don't need nested lists. If you want to really have a matrix then you'd require a slight modification of the code:

```
List<String> vegetables = new ArrayList<>(); // Fill the lists somehow
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();    

for(String vegetable : vegetables) {
    List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
    row.add(vegetable);
    for(String fruit : fruits) {
        row.add(fruit);
    }
    matrix.add(row);
}
```

That would create rows with items `VegetableN, Fruit1, Fruit2, Fruit3` where N is the number of the vegetable row.

Comment: Wow! The first code was exactly what I needed. I am very new to programming so I am unfamiliar with some things. My main goal is to compare strings of different groups (fruits & vegetables as an example) for textual similarity. I believe I can move forward now

Comment: @TomWilson If my answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted using the green check mark under the voting buttons so that it disappears from the unanswered section.